Replaced motherboard on HP Z2 system and boot device NVMe is not detected
I have a HP Z2 system that has a motherboard that was replaced by the Windows admin. The system was handed to me and it is not booting. The Ubuntu 20.04.1 root disk was encrypted using luks. The customer has live data on the disk on /dev/nvmen1p3. Secure Boot and fast boot are disabled.  During the boot, system is not able to unencrypt the drive (cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/....) and finally falls into initramfs. I am able to use CD/DVD and get into the rescue mode, but not able to mount any of the disk partition to fix things out (like fsck or something).  Boot-Repair just detected the drive is encrypted that is all and did not come up with any other options.

Take a look at the following link for some pointers. https://pcxserver.com/2023/01/move-luks-encrypted-partition-to-new-device/

Thanks David for the suggestion but, I am not able to see any drives at all.

External hard drive enclosures are so cheap that they are practically free. Boot from an Ubuntu live USB with the external hard drive enclosure attached, and use the built-in GParted  app in an Ubuntu live session to reformat the encrypted drive.

This question is similar to: Full disk encryption has rendered my workstation unusable. Want to start from scratch. How can I get it to boot to GDM?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks Karel for the suggestion.  I think that is what I am leaning towards but have to see if customer  has the funds and willing to go that route.
